# How C# Open XML center table cell text for Word

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm creating a word table using Open XML. How do I center the text in a cell?
Here is a simple example I tried which does not center the text...

```
var row = new TableRow();
var cell = new TableCell();
var par = new Paragraph();
var run = new Run(new Text("Hello"));

par.Append(new Justification() {  Val = JustificationValues.Center });
par.Append(run);
cell.Append(par);
row.Append(cell);
```